# Search - find closest node to n different start points (uniform cost)

Tags: algorithm, search, closest

Suppose I had a node path where the cost of travelling between each node is uniform. I'm trying to find the closest node that 2 or more nodes can travel to. Closest being measured as the cumulative cost of reaching the common node from all start points.

[image]

If I wanted to find the closest common node to node A and B, that node would be E.

A -> E (2 cost)

B -> E (1 cost)

If I wanted to find the closest common node to node A, B, C, that node would be F.

A -> F (3 cost)

B -> F (2 cost)

C -> F (1 cost)

And if I wanted to find the closest common node between node G, E, no node is possible.

So there should be two outputs: either the closest node or an error message stating that it cannot reach one another.

I would appreciate if I could be given a algorithm that can achieve this. A link to a article, psudocode or any language is fine, below is some python code that represents the graph above in a `defaultdict(list)` object.

```
from enum import Enum
from collections import defaultdict 

class Type(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
    D = 4
    E = 5
    F = 6
    G = 6


paths = defaultdict(list)

paths[Type.A].append(Type.D)
paths[Type.D].append(Type.G)
paths[Type.D].append(Type.E)
paths[Type.B].append(Type.E)
paths[Type.E].append(Type.F)
paths[Type.C].append(Type.F)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would break this down in a couple of smaller problems: 1. find the distance to each node from a starting node (use a BFS) 2. find the cost of each target node (simple addition) 3. find the minimum from a list of numbers. This should have `O(n * (E +V))` running time, with `n` the number of starting nodes and `E` and `V` the number of edges and vertices.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Thanks for the response. What do you mean by step 2?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @VincentvanderWeele for the suggestion:

Example cost of all nodes from A, B

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
   ___________________
A  0  X  X  1  2  3  2
B  X  1  X  X  2  2  X
```

As an optimisation when working out the 2nd+ node you can skip any nodes that the previous nodes can not travel to, e.g.

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
   ___________________
A  0  X  X  1  2  3  2
B  X  X  X  X  2  2  X
      ^
```

Possible closest nodes:

```
E = 2 + 2 = 4
F = 2 + 3 = 5
```

Result is E since it has the lowest cost